# How come the following x86_64 assembly gives me a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So far I've been learning to write some x86_64 assembly. I read that you can subtract the RSP to grow the stack downwards and allocate space, so I wrote the following code:

```
push %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
subq $16, %rsp
movq $200, -8(%rsp)
movq $300, -16(%rsp)
popq %rbp
retq
```

From my understanding, this will make a function where it sets up a the stack frame, then it allocates 16 bytes on the stack and sets the values at -8 and -16 to 200 and 300 respectively.
However, when I run this with gcc, I get a segmentation fault. Though if I remove the `sub` part of the program, it works perfectly. I assume I've misunderstood something, so what is actually going on here?

Comment: You need to free the space you allocated. Either by moving `rbp` back to `rsp` or by undoing the `sub`.

Comment: @Jester, so could I do the opposite of subtract and add 16 onto rsp?

Comment: Yes, if a frame pointer is not used, that's the usual way. When you do have a frame pointer as in your case, it's normally just moved back to `rsp`.

Comment: Whoa! Don't you mean `(%rBp)` here?

Comment: You mean `-8(%rbp)` and `-16(%rbp)` if you intend to write those values to the part of the stack that you just allocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jester says, the problem is that when you `pop %rbp` / `ret`, the stack pointer is pointing somewhere else, so you're not getting the old `%rbp` and the return address.  (You never write to the locations you pop, due to another potential-bug, so I can't tell you exactly which invalid address you `ret` to.)

If you make a stack frame at all (`mov %rsp, %rbp`), then it's normal to use offsets relative to `%rbp`.  Fun fact: `movq $200, -8(%rbp)` takes [one byte less machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400) than the equivalent `movq $200, 8(%rsp)`.  (Using `%rsp` as the base register unfortunately always requires a SIB byte to encode the effective address.)

Using `%rbp` also means the expression that references any given stack address doesn't change even if you're pushing/popping stuff (common in 32bit code with a stack-args ABI, but rare in 64bit code.  64bit gcc switched to -fomit-frame-pointer before 32bit).

---

Your `movq $200, -8(%rsp)` uses space outside the 16B you reserved.  This is the "other potential bug" I referred to earlier.

Using up to 128B below the current `%rsp` is actually *NOT* an error in the SysV ABI: asynchronous events (signal handlers and so on) avoid clobbering the [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)), so small functions that don't call any other functions can avoid spending instructions modifying `%rsp` to reserve space.  x86-64 has 15 general-purpose registers (not counting the stack pointer), so small and medium size functions typically don't need to use the stack other than to save/restore call-preserved registers.  Or for local arrays.

The Windows ABI doesn't use a red zone, so memory below `%rsp` can potentially be stepped on, even when you don't do it yourself with a `call`.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links about calling conventions / ABIs.